# Proving that a matrix is invertible without using determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, alternative-proof

> Prove if $A$, $B$, and $C$ are square matrices and $ABC = I$, then $B$ is invertible and  $B^{-1}= CA$.

I know that this proof can be done by taking the determinant of $ABC=I$ and showing that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are invertible and then finding the inverse of $B$. However, in this chapter of the book, we have not yet learned determinants so I would like to solve the problem without determinants. My proof method involves using a contradiction and is as follows:

Assume ${C^{-1}}$ does not exist, then $\exists$ $x$ $\neq$ $0$ such that $Cx = 0$.
$ABCx =Ix$

$AB0 = x$

$0=x$, which is a contradiction since we know that $x$ $\neq$ $0$, and therefore ${C^{-1}}$ exists.

$AB$${C^{-1}}$ $=I$${C^{-1}}$

$AB=$${C^{-1}}$

WLOG, B is invertible

$CAB =C$${C^{-1}}$

$CAB = I$

$CAB$${B^{-1}}$ $=I$${B^{-1}}$

$CA=$${B^{-1}}$

My question is if it is correct to assume ${C^{-1}}$ does not exist since the proof does not mention anything about ${C^{-1}}$ existing or not.

Comment: possible duplicate? [If ABC non-singular prove that A, B and C non-singular too](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1551538/289977).

Comment: What do you know about inverses, at that point in the book? For instance, what definition and/or characterizations of inverses and invertible matrices do you have available?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I know An n × n matrix A is invertible when there exists an n × n matrix B such that AB = BA = I and if A is an invertible matrix, then the system of linear equations Ax = b has a
unique solution x = A^(-1)b. I used the second fact in my proof, where I made vector b a zero vector. So at this point in the book, I know nothing of elementary matrices or determinants.

Comment: @Jay Do you know that checking only one of those two equations ($AB=I$, for instance) is sufficient for invertibility, or do you have to check both conditions? Most of the answers build on this fact.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes, there is a proof in the textbook that shows this theorem

Answer (score 29):

It can be shown, via [elementary means](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2532661/414530), that if $M$ and $N$ are square matrices such that $MN = I$, then $NM= I$.

Thus, if $ABC := A(BC) = I$, then $(BC)A = B(CA) = I$, i.e., the matrix $B$ is invertible and $B^{-1}=CA$.

Answer (score 10):

A square matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if there is another matrix $A^{-1}$ such that $A^{-1}A=I$. In the express$ABC=I$, chose $X=AB$ and we have $XC=I$. Thus $C^{-1}=X$. Similarly show $A$ is invertible. Now,
$$ABC=I$$
$$AB=C^{-1}$$
$$CAB=I$$
$$CA=B^{-1}$$

Comment: The first statement is only true for square matrices, since $A^{-1}A=I$ implies $AA^{-1}=I$. However, for matrices in general, it should be "A matrix $A$ is invertible iff. there is another matrix $A^{-1}$ which satisfies $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}=I$.

Comment: @ErlendGraff noted and edited!

Answer (score 6):

A square matrix is invertible if and only if its rank is $n$.

Also, we know that $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \le \min(\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B) )$

In this question

$$ABC=I$$

Hence $\operatorname{rank}(ABC)=n$

$$n \le \min(\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B), \operatorname{rank}(C) )$$

Hence $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(B) =\operatorname{rank}(C)=n$ and they are all invertible.

Hence $B=A^{-1}C^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}=(A^{-1}C^{-1})^{-1}=CA$

Comment: +1 for no-nonsense proof that they must all be invertible. (Another way to phrase this: if one of the matrices were noninvertible, then there would have to be some subspace which is at some point in the composition chain mapped to zero, but then $ABC$ couldn't be the identity.) — However the question did also ask about $B^{-1} = CA$, which can't be shown that easily.

Answer (score 4):

Since, $ABC = I$, then $A$ is invertible (see below). Same with $C$ since $(AB)C=I$. The inverse of $C$ is $AB$. So, $B = A^{-1}C^{-1}$ and $BCA= I$. So, the inverse of $B$ is $CA$.

**Proof-sketch of AB=I $\implies$ A and B are invertible and they are inverses of each other**

Consider the linear transformations induced by matrices $A$ and $B$ on $\mathbb R^n$. For, convenience I will represent the corresponding linear transformations by $A$ and $B$ as well. Since $AB=I$, it implies the composition of linear transformations $A$ and $B$ is the identity linear transformation. So, $B$ is an injective linear transformation and $A$ is a surjective linear transformation. Since, we are in a finite-dimensional vector space this implies both $A$ and $B$ are invertible linear transformation (by rank-nullity theorem). So, $A$ and $B$ are invertible as matrices. Also not that since $AB=I$, we get $BABA=BA$. Now by multiplying inverse of $A$ and $B$ from right on both sides, we get $BA=I$ as well. Now, from the definition inverse of matrices, we get $A$ and $B$ are inverses of each other.

Comment: The first statement is not just the definition of invertible matrices. It requires a non-trivial proof.

Comment: I edited my answer.